# What are the best sorting algorithms when 'n' is very small?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

In the critical path of my program, I need to sort an array (specifically, a C++ std::vector<int64_t>, using the gnu c++ standard libray).  I am using the standard library provided sorting algorithm (std::sort), which in this case is introsort.

I was curious about how well this algorithm performs, and when doing some research on various sorting algorithms different standard and third party libraries use, almost all of them care about cases where 'n' tends to be the dominant factor.

In my specific case though, 'n' is going to be on the order of 2-20 elements.  So the constant factors could actually be dominant.  And things like cache effects might be very different when the entire array we are sorting fits into a couple of cache lines.

What are the best sorting algorithms for cases like this where the constant factors likely overwhelm the asymptotic factors?  And do there exist any vetted C++ implementations of these algorithms?

Comment: For really small N sometimes the utter stupidity of bubblesort wins out. For 2-20 elements, I'd give it a shot.

Comment: The actual answer will depend on things like your hardware (cache size in particular), so the only way to know for sure is to measure.  Also, don't bother with this until you've verified with an actual profiler that this sorting is actually a bottleneck.

Comment: I've always had a hunch that selection sort is fastest when n is small, due to having drastically fewer writes than insertion or bubble sorts.

Comment: For very small number of items, you could take a look at sorting networks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network

Comment: Sorting networks are great for hardware, but ineffective for most software, probably including this case.

Comment: Likely for very small number of elements you can simply unroll it. Also, less likely but there's a trick on some many-core sync architectures if this occurs right after input (e.g. network card): you might have multiple cores listening to the input, each 'guessing' an order and only outputting from the core where order was correct. E.g. for 4 elements, you need 24 cores in sync. This is the theoretically fastest thing you can do with comparisons.

Comment: @user4581301 I actually used bubble sort in a commercial application where I expected n to be 4 or less on average. The next version completely blew that assumption out of the water and I'm sure the person who inherited that code said some unkind things behind my back.

Comment: @MarkRansom is that because you were wrong about the expectation on `n`? Or for some other reason?

Comment: That's unavoidable, but I'm a believer that one of the best metrics of good programming is how rarely your name is used as a curse word.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the program expanded its capabilities in a way I hadn't anticipated.

Comment: When `n` is very small then bubble sort is good. Especially if you use the already sorted test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Introsort takes your concern into account, and switches to an insertion sort implementation for short sequences.

Since your STL already provides it, you should probably use that.

Answer (score 2):

Insertion sort or selection sort are both typically faster for small arrays (i.e., fewer than 10-20 elements).

Comment: Most implementations of `std::sort` use insertion sort when they're processing ~16 elements.

Comment: yeah best-case complexity is O(n) i.e. why

Comment: @Ameya My understanding of why is "pipeline stalls expensive so optimize for branch prediction".

Comment: Adding to @Ameya's answer use Insertion sort when there are repeating elements as Insertion sort is stable while Selection sort isn't. Stable sorting algorithm maintain the order of occurrences of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJJTYQYB1JQ

A simple linear insertion sort is really fast. Making a heap first can improve it a bit.

Sadly the talk doesn't compare that against the hardcoded solutions for <= 15 elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know the fastest way to do anything without knowing *exactly* what the "anything" is.

Here is *one possible* set of assumptions:

- We don't have any knowledge of the element structure except that elements are comparable. We have no useful way to group them into bins (for radix sort), we must implement a comparison-based sort, and comparison takes place in an opaque manner.
- We have no information about the initial state of the input; any input order is equally likely.
- We don't have to care about whether the sort is stable.
- The input sequence is a simple array. Accessing elements is constant-time, as is swapping them. Furthermore, we will benchmark the function purely according to the expected number of comparisons - not number of swaps, wall-clock time or anything else.

With that set of assumptions (and possibly some other sets), the best algorithms for small numbers of elements will be hand-crafted [sorting networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network), tailored to the exact length of the input array. (These always perform the same number of comparisons; it isn't feasible to "short-circuit" these algorithms conditionally because the "conditions" would depend on detecting data that is already partially sorted, which still requires comparisons.)

For a network sorting four elements (in the known-optimal five comparisons), this might look like (I did not test this):

```
template<class RandomIt, class Compare>
void _compare_and_swap(RandomIt first, Compare comp, int x, int y) {
    if (comp(first[x], first[y])) {
        auto tmp = first[x];
        arr[x] = arr[y];
        arr[y] = tmp;
    }
}

// Assume there are exactly four elements available at the `first` iterator.
template<class RandomIt, class Compare>
void network_sort_4(RandomIt first, Compare comp) {
    _compare_and_swap(2, 0);
    _compare_and_swap(1, 3);
    _compare_and_swap(0, 1);
    _compare_and_swap(2, 3);
    _compare_and_swap(1, 2);
}
```

---

In real-world environments, of course, we will have different assumptions. For small numbers of elements, with real data (but still assuming we must do comparison-based sorts) it will be difficult to beat naive implementations of insertion sort (or bubble sort, which is effectively the same thing) that have been compiled with good optimizations. It's really not feasible to reason about these things by hand, considering both the complexity of the hardware level (e.g. the steps it takes to pipeline instructions and then compensate for branch mis-predictions) and the software level (e.g. the relative cost of performing the swap vs. performing the comparison, and the effect that has on the constant-factor analysis of performance).